# Android background service to connect TCP server and handle message

Tags: android, multithreading, service, client, message

According to an google example, i write an android client for a  connection protocol based on TCP Socket server can send and receive information and it works good. But now I want it to become a background service for these transactions, after I left the application it also can notify me the message in time, I think a couple of days, but without success, someone can give me some help? Very grateful!

### MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        Handler.Callback, ChatFragment.MessageTarget {

    public static final String TAG = "rolingbaby";

    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0x400 + 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_SEND = 0x400 + 2;
    public static final String SERVER_URL = "192.168.191.2";
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 7838;

    private Handler handler = new Handler(this);
    private ChatFragment chatFragment;

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_URL);
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected success!");
            new MyTask1(((ChatFragment.MessageTarget)    this).getHandler(),
                    address).execute();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, chatFragment, "trans")
                .commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                Log.d(TAG, readMessage);
                (chatFragment).pushMessage("Rec: " + readMessage);
                break;

            case MESSAGE_SEND:
                Object obj = msg.obj;
                (chatFragment).setChatManager((ChatManager) obj);

        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

### Pivotal code in ChatFragment

```
public interface MessageTarget {
    public Handler getHandler();
}

public void setChatManager(ChatManager obj) {
    chatManager = obj;
}

public void pushMessage(String readMessage) {
    adapter.add(readMessage);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

### MyTask

```
    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private static final String TAG = "ClientSocketHandler";
    private Handler handler;
    private ChatManager chat;
    private InetAddress mAddress;
    private static final int timeOut = 5000;

    public MyTask(Handler handler, InetAddress serverAddress) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.mAddress = serverAddress;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.bind(null);
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mAddress.getHostAddress(),
                    MainActivity.SERVER_PORT), timeOut);
            Log.d(TAG, "Launching the I/O handler");
            chat = new ChatManager(socket, handler);
            new Thread(chat).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ChatManager getChat() {
        return chat;
    }

}
```

### ChatManager

```
    public class ChatManager implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket = null;
    private Handler handler;

    public ChatManager(Socket socket, Handler handler) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    private InputStream iStream;
    private OutputStream oStream;
    private static final String TAG = "ChatHandler";
    public  static String  readMessage;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            iStream = socket.getInputStream();
            oStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_SEND, this)
                    .sendToTarget();

            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = iStream.read(buffer);
                    if (bytes == -1) {
                        break;
                    }else{
                        readMessage = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                    }

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    Log.d(TAG, "Rec:" + String.valueOf(buffer));
                    handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ,
                            bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            oStream.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

}
```